# Spring ignores Beans, Qualifier and Transactional

Tags: spring, spring-boot, annotations

Hi trying to set simple rest controller with several databases. Problem is Spring ignores both Transactional from my service, it always go to @Primary. Also Spring ignores the Qualifier inside DataSourceTransactionaManager and seems to go to default @Primary. Anyone help much appreciated.

edit: added import statements.. hikari imports i due too i changed the code little bit and instead use hikari database and also tried entitymanager..but neither of those things helped..

```
package com.example.miniredditbackend.user;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class UserService implements UserSer{

    private UserRepo userRep;
    @Autowired
    public UserService(UserRepo userRep){
        this.userRep = userRep;
    }

    @Override
   @Transactional("tm1")
    public User createUser(User user){

        return userRep.save(user);
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.miniredditbackend.user;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;



@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityuser",
        transactionManagerRef = "tm2",
        basePackages = {
                "com.example.miniredditbackend.user"
        }
)
public class userDatabase {

    @Bean(name = "userdb")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "userdatabase.datasource")
    public DataSource userdb(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }


    @Bean(name = "entityuser")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityU(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
                                                          @Qualifier ("userdb") DataSource datasource){
        return builder.dataSource(datasource).packages("com.example.miniredditbackend.user").persistenceUnit("usersx").build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "tm2")
    public PlatformTransactionManager tm2(@Qualifier ("entityuser") EntityManagerFactory entityuser){
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityuser);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the import statements in your code.

Comment: sorry new to this..what statements you want? Above is the service class and the configuration class. Then i basically just have one rest controller class, repo class and user class. I played around with it a little more and splitted the databases configuration class to 3 classes.. it became even weirder..now Spring doesnt even go to Primary but always user database configuration class and also continues to ignore Transactional.

Comment: added import statements.. just woke up before didnt understand what you meant hehe..

Comment: Looks like you are using Spring Data JPA as well, you will need to instruct this as well on which entitymanager and transaction manager to use, else it will just use the `@Primary` one.

Comment: updated with the new code.. that btw is exactly from an example that should work.. But it doesnt for me.. when i save something it always go to above userDatabase which funny enough is not even Primary any longer.. i put that on the postDatabase...but spring seems to love my userDatabase class.. i have no idea whats going on..

Comment: It doesn't matter that it isn't primary, it is tied to your entitymanager, which is being used, hence that will all go there.

Comment: i have no idea how this works.. but it works now when  i split them up in different packages..thanks for taking the time..